# Limit number of positions (height of elements list) displayed in ScrollView and ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, scrollview

I have `ScrollView` with `ForEach` elements inside
I want to limit `ScrollView` space to display only first 3 or 4 elements and rest after user scrolls down the list

This is the `ScrollView` code:

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(elementsNames, id: \.self) { elementName in
                    HStack {
                        HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            [some View]
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        if elementName == selection {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .frame(minWidth: 200, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .if(elementName == selection) {
                        $0
                            .background {
                                Color.accentColor
                            }
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
```

And it displays like:

[image]

I want however to display it like this:

[image]

With the rest elements hidden until user scrolls to them.

Comment: That's what a [List](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/) is for.

Comment: @DonMag can you elaborate about this?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an idea to set maxHeight value for the whole view implementing ScrollView and it is what I wanted.

```
SelectionDropdown()
    .frame(maxHeight: 300)
```